# How to treat different (multiple) measurements on the same subject over time?

Tags: anova, mixed-model

Let's say I am interested in some microscopic measurements on a subject, for example, the pore sizes on my hand.  I want to see how putting my hand under a humidifier changes the pore size over time, so I put one area of my hand under the microscope and measure about 50 pores to get a baseline.  After sticking my hand in the humidifier, I measure pore sizes from the same area of my hand at a number of set time points, but there's no way I can guarantee that I am measuring the exact same pores over time.

Then I can ask a few of my friends to do the same thing, so I have the same treatment for a total of 3 subjects.  Then, perhaps I want to compare this to another 3 people who I ask to stick their hand in a desiccator instead of a humidifier to see the difference.

I am thinking of using a mixed ANOVA to analyze the data set from these results; however, I don't know how to account for the fact that although the pores measured are from the same subject, it is not the exact same pore being measured over time. Furthermore, I measure a different number of pores each time I put a hand under the microscope - let's say, between 40 and 80 pores measured. How can I analyze these data?